# Как получить значение индекса comboBox в моем проекте?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qcombobox

После нажатия кнопки **`"Выбрать насосы"`** на основном окне, необходимо зафиксировать выбранные индексы `comboBox` при нажатии кнопки **`"Сохранить"`** в дополнительном окне "Типоразмеры насосов".

Моя программа не может определить эти индексы через:

```
a = ui.comboBox_npv.currentIndex()
```

Файл [**GUI.py**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bTGq7aXhZdih7-XS-Sa8cMtsXMTYH3ua/view?usp=sharing) прикладываю отдельно, так как необходимо соблюдать ограничение в количество символов.

[image: Типоразмеры насосов]

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import time

from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
from pumps import Ui_PumpsWindow
from pumps2 import Ui_PumpsWindow2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

def PumpsWindow():
    global PumpsWindow
    PumpsWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_PumpsWindow()
    ui.setupUi(PumpsWindow)
    MainWindow.hide()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    PumpsWindow.show()
    ui.pushButton_save_pumps1.setEnabled(True)
    ui.pushButton_next_pumps1.setEnabled(False)
    ui.pushButton_save_pumps1.clicked.connect(save1)


def save1():
    global a
    ui = Ui_PumpsWindow()
    ui.setupUi(PumpsWindow)
    a = ui.comboBox_npv.currentIndex()
    ui.pushButton_save_pumps1.setEnabled(False)
    ui.pushButton_next_pumps1.setEnabled(True)
    ui.pushButton_next_pumps1.clicked.connect(PumpsWindow2)
    print(str(a))

def PumpsWindow2():
    global PumpsWindow2
    PumpsWindow2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_PumpsWindow2()
    ui.setupUi(PumpsWindow2)
    PumpsWindow.hide()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    PumpsWindow2.show()
    ui.pushButton_save_pumps2.setEnabled(True)
    ui.pushButton_next_pumps2.setEnabled(False)
    ui.pushButton_save_pumps2.clicked.connect(save2)


def save2():
    ui = Ui_PumpsWindow2()
    ui.setupUi(PumpsWindow2)
    ui.pushButton_save_pumps2.setEnabled(False)
    ui.pushButton_next_pumps2.setEnabled(True)
    ui.pushButton_next_pumps2.clicked.connect(returnToMainWindow)

def returnToMainWindow():
    ui.pushButton_pumps.hide()
    PumpsWindow2.hide()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    MainWindow.show()

def options():
    global density, viscosity, diameter, wall_thickness, length, start_height, final_height, ost_napor, podpor1_a, \
            podpor1_b, podpor2_a, podpor2_b, napor11_a, napor11_b, napor12_a, napor12_b, napor13_a, napor13_b, \
            napor14_a, napor14_b, napor21_a, napor21_b, napor22_a, napor22_b, napor23_a, napor23_b, napor24_a, \
            napor24_b, napor31_a, napor31_b, napor32_a, napor32_b, napor33_a, napor33_b, napor34_a, napor34_b
    density = float(ui.spinBox_Density.value())
    viscosity = float(ui.spinBox_Viscosity.value()) / 1000000
    diameter = float(ui.spinBox_Diameter.value()) / 1000
    wall_thickness = float(ui.spinBox_wall_thickness.value()) / 1000
    length = float(ui.spinBox_Length.value()) * 1000
    start_height = float(ui.spinBox_start_height.value())
    final_height = float(ui.spinBox_final_height.value())
    ost_napor = float(ui.spinBox_ost_napor.value())

ui.pushButton_pumps.clicked.connect(PumpsWindow)
ui.pushButton_calculate.clicked.connect(options)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**pumps.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_PumpsWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, PumpsWindow):
        PumpsWindow.setObjectName("PumpsWindow")
        PumpsWindow.resize(360, 250)
        PumpsWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(360, 250))
        PumpsWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(360, 250))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(PumpsWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 202, 141))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.comboBox_npv = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.comboBox_npv.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_npv.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_npv.setObjectName("comboBox_npv")
        self.comboBox_npv.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_npv.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_npv.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_npv.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_npv.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_npv, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 80))
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 80))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Arial\";")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_save_pumps1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_save_pumps1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 171, 70))
        self.pushButton_save_pumps1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"font: 24pt \"Arial\";\n"
"border: 2px solid black;\n"
"background-color: rgb(174, 159, 220) ;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 202);\n"
"background-color: rgb(177, 236, 170);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(255, 187, 178);\n"
"background-color: rgb(204, 234, 235);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_save_pumps1.setObjectName("pushButton_save_pumps1")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 10, 131, 141))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 80))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 80))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Arial\";")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.comboBox_nm.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm.setObjectName("comboBox_nm")
        self.comboBox_nm.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_next_pumps1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_next_pumps1.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_next_pumps1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 170, 171, 70))
        self.pushButton_next_pumps1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"font: 24pt \"Arial\";\n"
"border: 2px solid black;\n"
"background-color: rgb(174, 159, 220) ;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 202);\n"
"background-color: rgb(177, 236, 170);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(255, 187, 178);\n"
"background-color: rgb(204, 234, 235);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_next_pumps1.setObjectName("pushButton_next_pumps1")
        PumpsWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(PumpsWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PumpsWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, PumpsWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PumpsWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("PumpsWindow", "Типоразмеры насосов"))
        self.comboBox_npv.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ1250-260"))
        self.comboBox_npv.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ2500-230"))
        self.comboBox_npv.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ3600-230"))
        self.comboBox_npv.setItemText(3, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ7000-210"))
        self.comboBox_npv.setItemText(4, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ10000-210"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow", "Типоразмер насосов на подпорной станции"))
        self.pushButton_save_pumps1.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow", "Сохранить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow", "Типоразмер насосов на НПС"))
        self.comboBox_nm.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ1250-260"))
        self.comboBox_nm.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ2500-230"))
        self.comboBox_nm.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ3600-230"))
        self.comboBox_nm.setItemText(3, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ7000-210"))
        self.comboBox_nm.setItemText(4, _translate("PumpsWindow", "НМ10000-210"))
        self.pushButton_next_pumps1.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow", "Далее"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PumpsWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_PumpsWindow()
    ui.setupUi(PumpsWindow)
    PumpsWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**pumps2.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_PumpsWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, PumpsWindow2):
        PumpsWindow2.setObjectName("PumpsWindow2")
        PumpsWindow2.resize(510, 640)
        PumpsWindow2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(510, 640))
        PumpsWindow2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(510, 640))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(PumpsWindow2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_save_pumps2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_save_pumps2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 570, 251, 70))
        self.pushButton_save_pumps2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"font: 24pt \"Arial\";\n"
"border: 2px solid black;\n"
"background-color: rgb(174, 159, 220) ;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 202);\n"
"background-color: rgb(177, 236, 170);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(255, 187, 178);\n"
"background-color: rgb(204, 234, 235);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_save_pumps2.setObjectName("pushButton_save_pumps2")
        self.gridLayoutWidget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 511, 141))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_5.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_5")
        self.gridLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_5)
        self.gridLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_7.setObjectName("gridLayout_7")
        self.comboBox_npv1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_5)
        self.comboBox_npv1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv1.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv1.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_npv1.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_npv1.setObjectName("comboBox_npv1")
        self.comboBox_npv1.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_npv1.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_npv1.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_7.addWidget(self.comboBox_npv1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_5)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 80))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(9999, 80))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Arial\";")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_7.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.comboBox_npv2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_5)
        self.comboBox_npv2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv2.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_npv2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_npv2.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_npv2.setObjectName("comboBox_npv2")
        self.comboBox_npv2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_npv2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_npv2.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_7.addWidget(self.comboBox_npv2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 511, 141))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_6.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_6")
        self.gridLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_6)
        self.gridLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_8.setObjectName("gridLayout_8")
        self.comboBox_nm_5 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_6)
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_5")
        self.comboBox_nm_5.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_5.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_5.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_5, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_7 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_6)
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_7")
        self.comboBox_nm_7.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_7.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_7.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_7, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_6 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_6)
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_6")
        self.comboBox_nm_6.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_6.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_6.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_6, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_8 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_6)
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_8")
        self.comboBox_nm_8.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_8.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_8.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_8, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_6)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 80))
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(9999, 80))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Arial\";")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_7 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 420, 511, 141))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_7.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_7")
        self.gridLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_7)
        self.gridLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_9.setObjectName("gridLayout_9")
        self.comboBox_nm_9 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_7)
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_9")
        self.comboBox_nm_9.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_9.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_9.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_9.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_9, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_11 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_7)
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_11")
        self.comboBox_nm_11.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_11.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_11.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_9.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_11, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_10 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_7)
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_10")
        self.comboBox_nm_10.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_10.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_10.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_9.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_10, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_12 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_7)
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_12")
        self.comboBox_nm_12.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_12.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_12.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_9.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_12, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_7)
        self.label_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 80))
        self.label_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(9999, 80))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Arial\";")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_5, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_8 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 140, 511, 141))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_8.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_8")
        self.gridLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_8)
        self.gridLayout_10.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_10.setObjectName("gridLayout_10")
        self.comboBox_nm_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_8)
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_1")
        self.comboBox_nm_1.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_1.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_1.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_10.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_8)
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_3")
        self.comboBox_nm_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_3.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_10.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_3, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_8)
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_2")
        self.comboBox_nm_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_2.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_10.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox_nm_4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.gridLayoutWidget_8)
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setStyleSheet("font: 11pt \"Arial\";")
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setObjectName("comboBox_nm_4")
        self.comboBox_nm_4.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_4.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_nm_4.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_10.addWidget(self.comboBox_nm_4, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_8)
        self.label_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 80))
        self.label_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(9999, 80))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("font: 16pt \"Arial\";")
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_10.addWidget(self.label_6, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.pushButton_next_pumps2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_next_pumps2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(249, 570, 260, 70))
        self.pushButton_next_pumps2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"font: 24pt \"Arial\";\n"
"border: 2px solid black;\n"
"background-color: rgb(174, 159, 220) ;\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 202);\n"
"background-color: rgb(177, 236, 170);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"border: 2px solid rgb(255, 187, 178);\n"
"background-color: rgb(204, 234, 235);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_next_pumps2.setObjectName("pushButton_next_pumps2")
        PumpsWindow2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(PumpsWindow2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PumpsWindow2)

    def retranslateUi(self, PumpsWindow2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PumpsWindow2.setWindowTitle(_translate("PumpsWindow2", "Диаметры рабочих колёс"))
        self.pushButton_save_pumps2.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow2", "Сохранить"))
        self.comboBox_npv1.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "525"))
        self.comboBox_npv1.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "500"))
        self.comboBox_npv1.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "475"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow2", "Диаметр рабочего колеса на подпорной станции"))
        self.comboBox_npv2.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "525"))
        self.comboBox_npv2.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "500"))
        self.comboBox_npv2.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "475"))
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_5.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_7.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_6.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_8.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow2", "Диаметр рабочего колеса на НПС2"))
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_9.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_11.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_10.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_12.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow2", "Диаметр рабочего колеса на НПС3"))
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_1.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_3.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_2.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setItemText(0, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "460"))
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setItemText(1, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "418"))
        self.comboBox_nm_4.setItemText(2, _translate("PumpsWindow2", "385"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow2", "Диаметр рабочего колеса на НПС1"))
        self.pushButton_next_pumps2.setText(_translate("PumpsWindow2", "Далее"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PumpsWindow2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_PumpsWindow2()
    ui.setupUi(PumpsWindow2)
    PumpsWindow2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам советую научиться составлять минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который касается вашей текущей проблемы, а не выставлять ваш полный проект, в котором не просто разобраться.

Я попробовал что-то сделать для вас, проверьте:

```
import sys
# ? import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
from pumps import Ui_PumpsWindow
from pumps2 import Ui_PumpsWindow2


# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class PumpsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_PumpsWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class PumpsWindow2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_PumpsWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.cb_npv_currentIndex =  None                             # ----> a
        
        self.pushButton_pumps.clicked.connect(self.pumps_window)
        self.pushButton_calculate.clicked.connect(self.options)     
        
    def pumps_window(self):
        self.pumpsWindow = PumpsWindow()                              # !!! +++
        self.hide()
        self.pumpsWindow.show()
        
        self.pumpsWindow.pushButton_save_pumps1.setEnabled(True)
        self.pumpsWindow.pushButton_next_pumps1.setEnabled(False)
        self.pumpsWindow.pushButton_save_pumps1.clicked.connect(self.save1)

    def save1(self):
#        a = ui.comboBox_npv.currentIndex()
        self.cb_npv_currentIndex = self.pumpsWindow.comboBox_npv.currentIndex()

        print(f'\nself.cb_npv_currentIndex = {self.cb_npv_currentIndex}\n') #

        self.pumpsWindow.pushButton_save_pumps1.setEnabled(False)
        self.pumpsWindow.pushButton_next_pumps1.setEnabled(True)
        
#        ui.pushButton_next_pumps1.clicked.connect(PumpsWindow2)
        self.pumpsWindow.pushButton_next_pumps1.clicked.connect(self.pumps_window2)
        
    def options(self):
#?        global density, viscosity, diameter, wall_thickness, length, start_height, final_height, ost_napor, podpor1_a, \
#?                podpor1_b, podpor2_a, podpor2_b, napor11_a, napor11_b, napor12_a, napor12_b, napor13_a, napor13_b, \
#?                napor14_a, napor14_b, napor21_a, napor21_b, napor22_a, napor22_b, napor23_a, napor23_b, napor24_a, \
#?                napor24_b, napor31_a, napor31_b, napor32_a, napor32_b, napor33_a, napor33_b, napor34_a, napor34_b

# ----> vvvvvvvvvvvvvv <---------------------------------------- что это  # ???  
        density        = float(self.spinBox_Density.value())
        viscosity      = float(self.spinBox_Viscosity.value()) / 1000000
        diameter       = float(self.spinBox_Diameter.value()) / 1000
        wall_thickness = float(self.spinBox_wall_thickness.value()) / 1000
        length         = float(self.spinBox_Length.value()) * 1000
        start_height   = float(self.spinBox_start_height.value())
        final_height   = float(self.spinBox_final_height.value())
        ost_napor      = float(self.spinBox_ost_napor.value())
# ----> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <---------------------------------------- что это  # ???  
        print(f'density={density}; ...; ost_napor={ost_napor}') #        


    def pumps_window2(self):
#        global PumpsWindow2
        self.pumpsWindow2 = PumpsWindow2()                            # !!! +++ 

#        ui = Ui_PumpsWindow2()
#        ui.setupUi(PumpsWindow2)

        self.pumpsWindow2.show()
        self.pumpsWindow.hide()
#        time.sleep(0.2)
#        PumpsWindow2.show()

        self.pumpsWindow2.pushButton_save_pumps2.setEnabled(True)
        self.pumpsWindow2.pushButton_next_pumps2.setEnabled(False)
        self.pumpsWindow2.pushButton_save_pumps2.clicked.connect(self.save2)

    def save2(self):
#        ui = Ui_PumpsWindow2()
#        ui.setupUi(PumpsWindow2)
        self.pumpsWindow2.pushButton_save_pumps2.setEnabled(False)
        self.pumpsWindow2.pushButton_next_pumps2.setEnabled(True)
        self.pumpsWindow2.pushButton_next_pumps2.clicked.connect(self.returnToMainWindow)


    def returnToMainWindow(self):
# ?        ui.pushButton_pumps.hide()
        self.show()
        self.pumpsWindow2.hide()
#        time.sleep(0.3)
#        MainWindow.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @profileVadim что не так?

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, когда в первый раз смотрел ваш ответ не нашёл кнопку "верного ответа". Сейчас выставил ваш как верный, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @profileVadim пожалуйста.